# Twilio twiml: Hold music during call transfer

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Do  Play verb with loop 0 value cause the music to play till the call is connected?

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play

Comment: In what situation are you talking about? I need a little more context to understand and answer this.

Comment: While receiving incoming call, I would like to play music till the call is connected to the receiver.

Comment: How are you currently connecting the calls together? Normally I would imagine that when you receive an incoming call you are connected to the caller immediately.

Comment: I need to dial two operators in sequence.  If the first operator is busy or not accepting the call, dial the second operator. If the second operator is busy or not accepting the call, go to voicemail. There is considerable time in dialing, whisper and gather etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Effectively in this situation you are looking to put your user in a queue while you dial your agents. This is how you'd do it:

First up, when you receive the incoming call you can respond with  [`<Enqueue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue) that directs a user into a queue. You can set a [`waitUrl` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue#attributes-waitUrl) that allows you to define either a music file or TwiML that will play while the user waits for the call to be answered.

```
<Response>
  <Enqueue waitUrl='/wait-music'>incoming</Enqueue>
</Response>
```

While your incoming caller is waiting, you can then start [making calls to your agents using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls). Once an agent connects and accepts the whisper you would then join the calls by dialling the [`<Queue>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/queue).

```
<Response>
  <Dial><Queue>incoming</Queue></Dial>
</Response>
```

With this method you'd need to maintain whether your user has been answered yet and manually handle whether to [redirect their call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress) from the queue to more TwiML to [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) a voicemail.

There is a more robust way to set all this up. It still requires enqueueing in the first place, but you should take a look at [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter). It's an automated call distribution service with configurable workflows. There's a bit more setup involved on the Twilio side, but TaskRouter will handle directing calls to your agents and allow you to define rules for how to handle a user who's been waiting too long. I recommend you check out the TaskRouter documentation and then take a look at the [quickstart guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/taskrouter) as an example.

Let me know if that helps at all.